# Purpose of passing global vars to self-invoking function or "IIFE"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see a lot of this in older JavaScript

```
(function (w){

    w.bar = 'baz';

 })(window);
```

What is the advantage of the above, over

```
(function(){

    window.bar = 'baz';

})();
```

same goes for any `global variable`, or variable defined outside the `IIFE`.

Comment: same as passing `function f1(f){ console.log(f) } f1(1);` over `function f1(){ console.log(1) } f1();` It gives you an advantage of defining the parameter at run time (which may be defined at some other place).

Comment: [_Being able to place global objects in the local scope provides faster internal lookup speeds and performance_](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/)

Comment: @Rayon this should be the answer and not a comment

Comment: I agree. I know that link-only answers are discouraged, but that is a very good article and clearly answers the question.

Comment: Disagree with @Rayon.  OP is adding **one** variable to window, (o.k., it could be a few, but still a small number) it seems unlikely that the speed difference will be relevant.

Comment: @user949300 OP is not adding a variable but a key for an object.. I am fine with your answer but I doubt my comment is misleading..

Comment: Alex and Yuriy: is my answer sufficient?  Want more details?  My answers do tend to be terse, let me know if you want more explanation.

Comment: Let's give it a couple more days to see if anyone else has input, will accept an answer before the temporal window closes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Makes it explicit that you are using (and probably modifying) globals in the function.
2. Allows you to modify the behavior in the future.  Maybe you have a `mockWindow` for a unit test. Maybe you are using Node.js and you don't have a `window`, but want to add to the `globals` var instead.

p.s.  IMO the trivial performance gain mentioned by @Rayon is a red herring.

Answer (score 3):

Passing window is done because local variables are easier and faster to access than global variables ...this may show slight difference in performance . The  method really comes in handy with module patterns and/or dependency injection .

**Example**

```
var moduleFirst = (function(){
    var name = "harry";
    return {
        firstparam : name
    }
})();
var moduleTwo = (function(x){
    console.log(x.firstparam);
})(moduleFirst)
```

Output will be : harry

So when window gets passed in IIFE ; all of its revealed methods are available in a local variable .

Answer (score 3):

In practice there is not much (any?) difference wit the example you have given, but you have **probably oversimplified** it from the code you are actually looking at.

In a more realistic program, you will have scopes and calls backs which are triggered and run in the eventloop asynchronously, and you are binding the variable to a specific instance in a closure -- so;

```
(function (w){
    setTimeout(function(){w.bar = 'baz';},100);
})(window); 
window = window2;
```

The bar is still being set in the original window, since that is what is bound to `w` - where in

```
(function (){
    setTimeout(function(){window.bar = 'baz';},10);
})(window); 
window = window2;
```

It will be set in the instance window2, since that is how the window is bound when the execution of the code eventually happens.

In this example "window" is a global variable, but the same is the case regardless of the scope of the variable that is bound.

Answer (score 2):

By passing global objects like window, document, $ to IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression) one can enhance the performance by reducing the scope lookup time.
Remember Javascript looks for property at first in local scope and way up chaining till global scope. So accessing window object at local scope reduce the lookup time.